# strange error : object 'x' not found in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found very strange error in ggplot. I managed to combine stat_ecdf and geom_point (for designated percentiles only). After I put all the code together, it shows

```
"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Source of water' not found.
```

This is the code

```
wq_tr_nona<-wq_tr%>%
  filter(!is.na(pH))

per.tile<-c(0.10,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.90)
tile_pH<-data.frame(x=quantile(wq_tr_nona$pH, per.tile),
              y=per.tile)

wq_tr_nona%>%
      ggplot(aes(pH,colour=`Source of water`))+
      geom_line(stat = "ecdf")+
      geom_vline(xintercept = 8,linetype="dashed")+ 
      geom_point(data=tile_pH,aes(x=x, y=y))+ 
      theme(text = element_text(size = 16, family = "serif"),
            legend.position="none",
            legend.title=element_blank())+
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(sprintf("%1.0f", x*100),"%"))+ #making decimal to percent
      theme_classic()
```

then, I cut geom_point line

```
geom_point(data=tile_pH,aes(x=x, y=y))+
```

I shows good plot without any message. 
[image: the plot]
Is anybody here know the problem?
Thanks

Comment: It says there is no variable named `Source of water` in `wq_tr_nona`.

Comment: @Phil removing `geom_point(data=tile_pH,aes(x=x, y=y))+`  resulted in a plot that shows the variable `Source of water` _is_ included in `wq_tr_nona `... `Source of water` isn't included in the `tile_pH` df, but I'm not sure why that would matter. If @Gugi-Yogaswara posts some sample data I'd be happy to look into further

Comment: try add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to geom_point. The reason is you are passing your color aesthetic to the global ggplot call which geom_point tries to read, but you are passing different data to it, which does not contain this column. To avoid this, when using different data for your layers, I'd recommend just using `ggplot()+...` and passing the data to each geom separatley

Comment: Thanks a lot, inherit.aes works for me. Yeah, addressing new data in each geom could be better in some cases.